# Pandas data analysis; many to many matching

Tags: pandas, matching

I have 2 dataframes in pandas with Columns as Client ID, Security ID and Quantity. Each dataframe can have duplicate values for each row or more than one row for a client and security combination. How do I perform One to One matching followed by one to many, many to one and many to many matching. Only records that do not get matched on one to one match should be picked for one to many match and so on. In case of many the sum of quantities across more than one row of a dataframe should be considered. 
Thanks

```
Df1
Index   ClientID    SecurityID  Qty
0   CL1         S1          10
1   CL1         S1          20
2   CL1         S1          10
3   CL2         S1          10
4   CL2         S1          10
5   CL3         S2          20
```

Df2

```
Index ClientID SecurityID Qty
0     CL1      S1         10
1     CL1      S1         30
2     CL1      S1         10
3     CL2      S1         10
4     Cl2      S1         10
5     CL3      S2         10
6     Cl3      S2         10
7     Cl3      S2         10
```

For CL1 I would expect row 0(index) of DF1 to get matched with row 0 of DF2 on O2O(One to One) basis while rows 1 and 2 of DF1 should get matched on many to one (M2O) basis with row 1 of DF2. So row 2 of DF2 will remain unmatched for client CL1.

For Cl2 rows 3 and 4 of Df1 should be matched on O2O basis with rows 3 and 4 of DF2. So effectively there will be 2 O2O matches for this client.

For Cl3 row 5 of DF1 should match on one to many basis with rows 5 and 6 of DF2, so row 7 of DF2 will remain unmatched.

In SQL we have updates based on rownum, and in excel we have index-match feature, I couldn't find a similar one in Pandas that can help me earmark rows that got matched.

Comment: `I have 2 dataframes` - sample of them please

Comment: Take a look at [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html)

Comment: please add outputs of `df1.head(5)` and `df2.head(5)` in the question.